# How can I modify the mirrored side of an object?

Tags: mirror

[image]

I need to modify the mirrored side of the object to add an asymmetrical feature. I haven't found a solution for this yet, any help?

Also, how can I make the mirrored side a part of the object that it is mirroring?
As in, make it modifiable.

Comment: Apply the mirror modifier

Comment: I can't believe I'm so stupid. Thanks so much!